# Adding an extra node to collapsible D3 Tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3 V3 for a vertical collapsible tree. A typical node in my data contains about 10-15 child nodes, but I only display top N nodes using the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Collapsible Tree Example</title>

    <style>
        .node circle {
            fill: #fff;
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 3px;
        }

        .node text {
            font: 12px sans-serif;
        }

        .link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #ccc;
            stroke-width: 2px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- load the d3.js library -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var treeData = [{
            "name": "Top Level",
            "parent": "null",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Level 2: A",
                "parent": "Top Level",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Son of A",
                    "parent": "Level 2: A"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Daughter of A",
                    "parent": "Level 2: A"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Son of A",
                    "parent": "Level 2: A"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Daughter of A",
                    "parent": "Level 2: A"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Son of A",
                    "parent": "Level 2: A"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Daughter of A",
                    "parent": "Level 2: A"
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Level 2: B",
                "parent": "Top Level",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Son of B",
                    "parent": "Level 2: B"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Daughter of B",
                    "parent": "Level 2: B"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Son of B",
                    "parent": "Level 2: B"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Daughter of B",
                    "parent": "Level 2: B"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Son of B",
                    "parent": "Level 2: B"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Daughter of B",
                    "parent": "Level 2: B"
                }
                ]
            }
            ]
        }];

        // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
        var margin = {
            top: 40,
            right: 120,
            bottom: 20,
            left: 120
        },
            width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var i = 0;

        var tree = d3.layout.tree()
            .size([height, width]);

        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function (d) {
                return [d.x, d.y];
            });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        root = treeData[0];

        update(root);

        function update(source) {

            function topN(node, N) {
                if (node.children) {
                    node.children = node.children.slice(0, N);

                    // Now run the function on each child:
                    node.children.forEach(function (x) {
                        topN(x, N);
                    });
                }
            }

            topN(source, 3);

            // Compute the new tree layout.
            var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                links = tree.links(nodes);

            // Normalize for fixed-depth.
            nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                d.y = d.depth * 100;
            });

            // Declare the nodes…
            var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                .data(nodes, function (d) {
                    return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                });





            // Enter the nodes.
            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });

            nodeEnter.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 10)
                .style("fill", "#fff");

            nodeEnter.append("text")
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18;
                })
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.name;
                })
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);

            // Declare the links…
            var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                .data(links, function (d) {
                    return d.target.id;
                });

            // Enter the links.
            link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", diagonal);

        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

```
        function topN(node, N) {
        if (node.children) {
            node.children = node.children.slice(0, N);

            // Now run the function on each child:
            node.children.forEach(function (x) {
                topN(x, N);
            });
        }
    }
```

This way only the top N children are displayed. I would like to add an extra child node that is displayed, which when clicked will display the next N nodes (on the same level). How would I implement this?

NOTE: All nodes have multiple text and rect attributes that are displayed.

Comment: Please post a working snippet or fiddle

Comment: Added the snippet